# Rebind DatePicker Object To HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I've a **SyncFusion** date picker that I am using as follows:

```js
 var datepicker = null;
 $("#datepicker").hide();
 

$("#click").click(function(){
  $("#datepicker").show();
  
  datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ width: "255px" });
  datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');
});

$("#clickAgain").click(function(){
 $("#datepicker").hide();
 
  datepicker.destroy();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <input id="datepicker" type="text">
 
 <a id="click">Click Here</a>
 <!--<a id="clickAgain">Click Again</a>-->
```

This thing works but I am trying to do one thing here, though not sure if it's possible. When I click on **Click Here** anchor tag, it binds the date picker to `HTML` element. When I click again, it rebinds and gets repeated. So I am trying to reinitialize it and then bind to the `HTML` element once. Tried to use **destroy()** from **SyncFusion** documentation and it destroys when I use a separate click event.

My concern is to clear the appended element and rebind the date picker object using **Click Here** click event. Any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling refresh method, which destroys and renders the control again.
Reference: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/api/datepicker#refresh

```
$("#click").click(function () {
   if (datepicker) {
      datepicker.refresh();
   } else {
      $("#datepicker").show();
      datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ width: "255px" });
      datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');
   }
});
```

Else you can check the instance and then clear the appended element using destroy and render it again as per the below code.

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    if (datepicker) datepicker.refresh();
    $("#datepicker").show();
    datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ width: "255px" });
    datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');
});
```